# Constructor with variable number of arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to add a constructor that could allow a variable number of arguments.
caller is a function that could call other functions with their arguments(something simliar to thread but for calling functions only).
I already made it with a function template

```
template <class C,class ... _Args >
void caller(C(*f) ( _Args ... __args ), _Args ... __args ){(*f ) ( __args ...) ;}
```

But I need to have a class because it also should make an object of this class. something like this.

```
caller()
```

I made a class for caller with a constractor that could call other functions with a known number of arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
class caller  {
public:
caller(){std::cout<<"Constructor default";  }
caller(void (*Optype)(int),int a){Optype(a);std::cout<<"Constructor 1";  }
//*** Constructor for variable number of arguments**
};
```

and it works correctly with following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "caller"
using namespace std;
void foo(int a){
  cout<<a<<endl;
}
int main()
{
  caller c;
  caller(); 
  caller(foo,2);  
  return 1;
}
```

I want to know how can I add a constructor which works with different numbers of variables and is it possible it allows different types of variables too? I ask for something like the function template that I already made but in the class.

Comment: You can use the same way for constructor... (constructors might be `template`)

Comment: You already have the solution for your function (template argument packs), why not use it for your constructor as well?

Comment: If you can write a variadic free function, and you can write a regular constructor, you can make _some_ attempt to write a variadic constructor. Either it works, and you didn't need to ask a question, or it doesn't and you have a concrete compile error to ask about.

Comment: BTW names with leading double underscores, or a single underscore followed by an upper-case letter (ie, both `__args` and `_Args`) may be reserved for the implementation. It's a bad habit to use these in C++.

Comment: Also, instead of taking an actual pointer to a function, I suggest you look at how the standard library handles "callable" object passed as arguments: Through a simple template type. That way it's possible to pass *any* callable object, not only non-member functions, static member functions, or non-capturing lambdas.

Comment: "it also should make an object of this class" what is "it" and what is "this class" ? Do you want to store the function pointer passed to the constructor as a member?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a variadic list of arguments to the constructor you do this sort of thing:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test
{
    template<typename T>
    Test(T i)
    {
        std::cout << "Test(T i) -> i=" << i << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename T, typename... R>
    Test(T i, R... r)
        : Test(r...)
    {
        std::cout << "Test(T i, R... r) -> i=" << i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test a{1};    
    Test b{"A", 17};
    Test c{18, 2.5f, "B"};

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Avoid recursion with variadic template to speed up compilation. Folding expression would compile faster.

Comment: @jarod42 i was more showing how to pass a variadic than suggesting a full implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  @Treebeard answer I modified my code as below and it works.

```
using namespace std;
class thread {
public:
//default constructor
thread(){}
//other constructors
template<class C,typename... R> 
thread(C(*f), R... r){
    (*f ) ( r ...) ; } };


void foo(char a){
  cout<<a<<endl;
}
void foo1(int a,int b , int c){
  cout<<a+b+c<<endl;
}
int main()
{
  thread t1;
  thread();
  thread(foo,'Z');
  thread(foo1,2,3,100);
  return 1;
}
```